# Confused about using datastore for pagination on Python App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pagination, google-cloud-datastore

I'm building a Webapp2 application, and trying to find the best solution for pagination.
I found out the prevalent way is to use the **cursor**. For example:

```
# My solution is to get all cursors in the very first time
# For example, there will be 2 cursors for 3 pages 
# page1|c1|page2|c2|page3

page_size = 20
all = model.MyModel.gql(...)
...
if cursor:
   # Use cursor to get items
   list = all.with_curosr(...)
else:
   # Get all cursors and memcaching all cursors
   ...
```

I also tried another solution although I knew many people will consider it a bad solution:

```
# In this solution, I try to split query into many list
# page1(list1)|page2(list2)|page3(list3)

page_size = 20
all = list(model.MyModel.gql(...))
lists = [all[i:i+page_size] for i in range(0, len(all), page_size)]

# Client will send the page number to server side
list = []
if len(lists) > 0:
    list = lists[int(page_number)-1]
```

Here comes my question!
What is the advantages of using cursor ?

Both two solutions all need to execute **MyModel.gql(...)** to get data, and the first solution still have to execute **with_cursor(...)** to retrieve items.
It makes me so confused.

If you have better solutions or any suggestions for improving my solution, please share with me! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is a huge difference using cursors versus pages. when using cursors, its very efficient to get the next cursor result: O(1) or O(log n) at most.

with paging, the entire datastore query result needs to be scanned up to the page you request: O(n) per page request.

Thus something simple like iterating all pages using cursors would be O(n log n) at most, while using pages would be O(n^2). Not only does it take more time, it also takes more datastore reads because internally Google will still read all entries up to the page requested, then filter them out.

Thus it will also incur more costs regarding datastore reads and also can incur more instance hours if you have many requests and another instance is more likely to be launched.

See the official documentation about this: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries#Python_Offsets_versus_cursors

Comment: Thanks to your elaboration. Now I realized using cursors could reduce read operations than using offsets.